# how to use scipy tplquad properly?

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-integration

I am trying to do some simple triple integrals in physics using scipy's tplquad. As an example, I tried to integrate constant mass density of a unit ball(func d) over the unit cube. This doesn't work. However, if I integrate constant mass density of a unit cube(func f) over the unit cube, I get a result very quickly.

I thought the problem was with providing the constant integration limits as constants instead of functions. I fixed that using lambda, but still I can't get the integral.

```py
from scipy import integrate

''' returns the mass density at a point (x,y,z)'''
def d(z, x, y):
  return int(x**2 + y**2 + z**2 <= 1) # unit ball with constant density = 1 , here all orthogonal axes are principal 

def f(x,y,z):
    return 1

integrate.tplquad(d, -1, 1, lambda x: -1, lambda x: 1,lambda x, y: -1, lambda x, y: 1) # doesn't work / too slow
integrate.tplquad(f, -1, 1, lambda x: -1, lambda x: 1,lambda x, y: -1, lambda x, y: 1) # works fine
```

I expect the integral of d on the given range to be 4/3*pi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integrating a discontinuous function is a difficult numerical problem.

A work around is to define the integration domain as the unit ball:

```
from scipy import integrate
import numpy as np

''' returns the mass density at a point (x,y,z)'''
def d(z, x, y):
      return 1

integrate.tplquad(d, -1, 1,
                  lambda x: -np.sqrt(1-x**2), lambda x: np.sqrt(1-x**2),
                  lambda x, y: -np.sqrt(1-x**2-y**2), lambda x, y: np.sqrt(1-x**2-y**2))
# (4.188790204786397, 2.000470900043183e-09)
# 4/3*np.pi = 4.1887902047863905
```

Another not ideal solution is to smooth artificially the function. 
Using for instance the Logistic function, see [Analytic approximations of Heaviside_step_function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function#Analytic_approximations):

```
''' returns the mass density at a point (x,y,z)'''
def d(z, x, y):
    r2 = x**2 + y**2 + z**2
    smoothing_length = 0.1 # same unit as r2
    d = 1 - 1/(1 + np.exp(-2*(r2-1)/smoothing_length))
    return d

integrate.tplquad(d, -1, 1, lambda x: -1, lambda x: 1,lambda x, y: -1, lambda x, y: 1)
# (4.182852937567993, 3.021537155780628e-08)
```

The value `smoothing_length` have to be chosen with care.

[Monte Carlo integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_integration) could be the right method for more complex problems...

Answer (score 1):

Most numerical integration routines (such as `tplquad`) approximate the integral by using polynomials. This works well if the function is smooth. Unfortunately, characteristic functions are everything else *but* smooth since they have a discontinuous boundary. That's why `tplquad` fails.

If you want to approximate the volume of a domain, a reasonable approach would be to create a mesh of triangles (in 2D) or tetrahedra (in 3D) for it, and then add the volumes of the simplices. A examples for mesh generators are [pygmsh](https://github.com/nschloe/pygmsh) and  [pygalmesh](https://github.com/nschloe/pygalmesh) (a project of mine), but there are others.

If you actually want to *integrate* a function over the ball, you should probably take a look at [quadpy](https://github.com/nschloe/quadpy#ball) (another project of mine). It features many integration schemes for various domains, amongst them the ball. This

```py
import numpy
import quadpy

scheme = quadpy.ball.hammer_stroud_14_3()
val = scheme.integrate(
    lambda x: numpy.ones_like(x[0]),  # function to integrate
    [0.0, 0.0, 0.0],  # center
    1.0,  # radius
    )
print(val)  # 4.1887902047863905 == 4*pi/3
```

would integrate the function `1` over the unit ball using a scheme of degree 5, and it returns the exact the result.